# dynamic-form : idAttr is undefined when using element within jeasyui

Tags: jquery, html

I am using [Jeasyui](http://www.jeasyui.com) to create form element and I need to duplicate some element in the form with [jQuery Dynamic Form](http://sroucheray.org/blog/jquery-dynamic-form/).

JS:

```
// generate combobox with jeasyui
$('#empPhoneType').combobox({  
  url: '<?=BASE_URL?>mdm/employee/contacttype?t=mail',  
  valueField:'id',  
  textField:'name'  
}); 
// called to generate dynamic element
$('#phoneWrapper').dynamicForm('#phone-add', '#phone-remove', {limit:5});
```

HTML:

```
<form id="form"> 
      <label for="empPhone">Telepon</label>
      <div style="margin-bottom: 10px;" id="phoneWrapper"> 
            <select id="empPhoneType" name="empPhoneType"></select> 
            <input type="text" id="empPhone" name="empPhone"/>  
       </div>
      <a href="#" id="phone-remove">[ - ] &nbsp;</a>
      <a href="#" id="phone-add">[ + ]</a>

 ​</form>​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

when I run the code, the element is duplicated but it gives this error:

> TypeError: idAttr is undefined. 
>   newIdAttr = idAttr.slice(0,-1) + index,

but when I remove the initialize jeasyui >> $('#empPhoneType'), the element is duplicated and didn't give any error

can someone help me?

---

Ok, I has solved the issue.
the problem is in the `dynamic-form.js`
in the function `normalizeClone()` its run each function that loop `formFields` ("input, checkbox, select, textarea").

when it loop `formFields`, there is a variables trying to catch element id.
but there doesn't have the handling when the element has no id.
so I just put a handler to handling if the element is have no id.

original function:

```
elmnt.find(formFields).each(function(){ 
        var that = $(this);
        var idAttrs = that.attr("id");
        var nameAttr = that.attr("name"); 
        var origNameAttr = that.attr("origname");
        var newIdAttr = idAttrs.slice(0, -1) + index;
        match = matchRegEx.exec(nameAttr);

        if (idAttrs) {
            that.attr("name", match[1]+index+match[3]);



            that.attr("origid", idAttrs);

            elmnt.find("label[for='"+idAttrs+"']").each(function(){
                $(this).attr("for", newIdAttr);
            });
            that.attr("id", newIdAttr);
        }
    });
```

Adding a handler to the function:

```
elmnt.find(formFields).each(function(){ 
        var that = $(this);
        var idAttrs = that.attr("id");
        if (idAttrs) {
            var nameAttr = that.attr("name"); 
            var origNameAttr = that.attr("origname") || idAttrs.slice(0, -1);
            var newIdAttr = idAttrs.slice(0, -1) + index;
            match = matchRegEx.exec(nameAttr);

            if(match)
                that.attr("name", match[1]+index+match[3]);

            that.attr("origid", idAttrs);

            elmnt.find("label[for='"+idAttrs+"']").each(function(){
                $(this).attr("for", newIdAttr);
            });
            that.attr("id", newIdAttr);
        }
    });
```